# Converting Scientific Notation to float (string to float) in SQL (Redshift)

Tags: sql, database, casting, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert/cast a string of scientific notation (for example, '9.62809864308e-05') into a float in SQL.

I tried the standard method: CONVERT(FLOAT, x) where x = '9.62809864308e-05', but it returns the error message: Unimplemented fixed char conversion function - bpchar_float8:2585.

What I'm doing is very straightforward. My table has 2 columns: ID and rate (with rate being the string scientific notation that I am trying to cast to float). I added a 3rd column to my table and tried to populate the 3rd column with the float representation of x:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET 3rd_column = CONVERT(FLOAT, 2nd_column)
```

Data type of `2nd_column` is `CHAR(20)`

Furthermore, not every string float is in scientific notation -- some are in normal float notation. So I'm wondering if there is a built in function that can take care of all of this.

Thank you!

Comment: What datatype are your two columns exactly? I suggest you add a where clause to your update to pick and choose particular values to see if they work or not.

Comment: The datatype for the 2nd_column is: char(20) (so a string). Interesting, I only picked out the string floats that are non-scientific to cast and that still doesn't work -- trying to figure out why now but thanks so much for your suggestion!

Comment: and I guess 3rd_column is float? Does `SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, '9.62809864308e-05') ` work? I don't have access to Redshift now, just suggesting some troubleshooting options

Comment: Yes, that does actually! So the problem is not the scientific notation. I think I just figured out what the problem is -- there's a lot of white spaces in the string float -- that's probably what's messing things up.

Comment: OK so you might need to cast to VARCHAR first or trim it. Also take note of the lesson learnt: don't make assumptions,. whittle down to specific test cases Posting the actual code you tested really helps to do this - the update statement you posted is very different to your original assumption.

Comment: Yup! The white spaces are what's screwing things up -- the 3rd_column is now populated correctly. Thank you so much Nick!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that for any string representation of a float x, so let's say x = '0.00023' or x = '2.3e-04'

CONVERT(FLOAT, x) will Convert the data type of x from char (string) to float.

The reason why it didn't work for me was my string contained white spaces.